# Realizing singular homology boundaries as boundary restrictions of manifold maps, in smooth case

Tags: smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology, smooth-functions, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Let $\rho = \sum_j \sigma_j$, where the sum is finite, be a chain of singular $k$-simplices in $X$ (in the $k$th singular chain group of $X$, with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients).

For a $(k+1)$-dimensional [pseudomanifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomanifold) $K$ let $\partial K$ denote its boundary which should be a $k$-dimensional pseudomanifold.

If I'm not mistaken, we have the following:

> If $\rho$ is a $k$-boundary,
> then there exists an "orientable" $(k+1)$-dimensional pseudomanifold $W$,
> and a continuous map $f : W \rightarrow X$,
> such that the boundary restriction $\partial f : \partial W \rightarrow X$
> carries the triangulation on $\partial W$
> to the chain $\rho$ in $X$, with signs assigned as per some "outward" orientation on $\partial W$ from $W$.

---

Now we assume further that $X$ is a smooth manifold.

I was wondering, in this case, can we find $W,f$ satisfying the following additional conditions?

- $W$ has a smooth structure "smooth structure with corners" on each $n$-simplex;
- $f : W \rightarrow X$ is smooth on $W\setminus U$ for some collar neighborhood $U$ of $\partial W$ which can be made "arbitrarily thin"; and
- if each $\sigma_j$ is smooth, then $f$ can be assumed smooth on the whole of $W$.

(I think the 3rd bullet point would follow from the other 2, using e.g. Whitney approximation -type theorems.)

---

Edit: added the last condition, for the case of $\sigma_j$'s already smooth.

---

Edit: per the suggestion in the comment below, allowed $W$ to be a "pseudomanifold with boundary" instead of a manifold or arbitrary finite simplicial complex.

Comment: You are mistaken in your belief even in the "topological" case. For instance, it may so happen that $\rho$ is represented by a map $Y\to X$, where $Y$ is a compact oriented manifold which does not bound a compact  manifold $W$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for explaining this. Would the question be correctly formulated if instead W is relaxed to a continuous map of a finite simplicial complex into X, and we can still define smoothness in terms of the standard "smooth manifold with corner" structures on the k-simplices (ignoring issues at adjacent faces for now)?

Comment: Your edit now does not make sense either. You cannot take $\partial W$ to be the $k$-skeleton. You can ask for a complex $W$ which is a pseudo-manifold with boundary (this does make sense), such that $\partial W=Y$. However, then I cannot make sense of your smoothness requirements. At best, one can require smoothness on each simplex (which, I think, can be achieved).

Comment: For references, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20891/singular-homology-of-a-differential-manifold).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, thank you; evidently pseudomanifolds are the concept needed here.